# Varnish Issues - Not listening on 127.0.0.1 and certain pages returning 404

Tags: varnish

Have varnish running but it will only work if I use the IP address of the server in default.vcl instead of 127.0.0.1.

```
backend default {
    .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    .port = "82"; }
```

Certain pages on the site are also not loading properly and returning 404 errors. Added the following to default.vcl to not cache these sections but still returning 404. There are also subpages in the /jobs section, ex. /jobs/apply/.

```
 if (req.url ~ "^/jobs") {
    return (pass);
}

if (req.url ~ "^/ajax") {
    return (pass);
}
```

Sessions are also not being stored, $_SESSION['test'].

Comment: Is your backend-server on the same host as varnish? If so, is it listening on the loopback device? check with `netstat -tulpen` - you should see your apache/nginx listening on 0.0.0.0:[port]. 404 means document not found - unless you have a VCL that specifically creates that error, your backend is responsible for that!

Comment: Backend server is on the same server. Checked `netstat -tulpen` and see the 0.0.0.0:80 and 0.0.0.0:82 entries. The same pages work on the live server that doesn't have varnish. The site is using Wordpress on the live and new (varnish enabled) server.

Comment: Switched `.host = "127.0.0.1";` and getting the `/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` default site page.

Comment: Is your backend server configured to respond differently based on the IP that's being connected to?  What's the config look like for it?

Comment: Using cPanel. Haven't touched httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned CPanel.  By default, CPanel doesn't set up Apache VHosts to listen on `*:80`, it sets them up to listen to their individual IP addresses.  Thus, you aren't hitting the VHost you think you are.  You can test this easily; put a simple text file in your DocumentRoot, and you'll find that you cannot reach it using your browser through Varnish, but with Varnish disabled, that same address in your URL bar will load the file successfully.